# Python Pillow(PIL) Not completely recoloring gradients?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gradient

I am having an issue where I'm using Pillow to recolor an image that has a lot of soft gradients but it seems to not completely color the most translucent part of these gradients, with the recolored image having a gradient that is not as smooth. Is there a way to fix this issue? Example Images and current code below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccow.png)

Original Gradient: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccow.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFi75.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccow.png)

Recolored Gradient: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccow.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5iNa.png

[Here is the Original transparent PNG of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6d3w.png)

```
import random
import Owl_Attributes
from PIL import Image, ImageColor

# I create the image here and convert the color code to RGBA
RGB_im = image_base_accent3.convert("RGBA")

datas = RGB_im.getdata()


newData = []

for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 208 and item[1] == 231 and item[2] == 161:
        newData.append((255, 0, 0, item[3]))
    else:
        newData.append(item)
RGB_im.putdata(newData)

RGB_im.save('Owl_project_pictures\_final_RGB.png')
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and clarify what you are trying to do... *"colour the image with the most translucent something..."* and *"recoloring not completely recoloring..."* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple of things to consider:

- Inspect your images before you start work. Yours has an alpha channel that is pretty much pointless and irrelevant so I would discard that to save space and processing time.
- Using `for` loops over Python lists of pixels is slow, inefficient, and  error-prone in Python. Try to use built-in functions based on `C` code, or to use vectorised functions like Numpy.

On to your image. There are a whole load of shades and gradations of tone in your image and dealing with one separately through `if` statements is going to be difficult. I would suggest you want to use [HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) instead.

I think you want the basic result to be a very saturated red with the lightness dictated by the lightness of the original image.

So, I would make an image with:

- `Hue=0` (see lower part of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSL-HSV_hue_and_chroma.svg) diagram), and
- `Saturation=255` (i.e. fully saturated), and
- `Value` (i.e. brightness) of the original image.

In code that might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# ImageMagick command-line "equivalent"
# magick -size 599x452 xc:black xc:white \( VFi75.png -colorspace gray +level 0,60% \) +combine HSL result.png
    
from PIL import Image
    
# Load image and create HSV version
im  = Image.open('VFi75.png')
HSV = im.convert('HSV')

# Split into separate channels for processing, discarding Hue and Saturation
_, _, V = HSV.split()

# Synthesize Hue channel, same size as input image, filled with 0, to make Red
H = Image.new('L', (im.width, im.height), 0)

# Synthesize Saturation channel, same size as input image, filled with 255, to make fully saturated
S = Image.new('L', (im.width, im.height), 255)

# Recombine synthesized H, S and V (based on original image brightness) back into a recombined image
RGB = Image.merge('HSV', (H,S,V)).convert('RGB')

# Save processed result
RGB.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you wanted to make it lime green, you would change the Hue angle like this:

```
# Synthesize Hue channel, same size as input image, filled with 120, to make Lime Green
H = Image.new('L', (im.width, im.height), 120)
```

[image]

---

If you wanted to make it less saturated, you would change the saturation like this:

```
# Synthesize Saturation channel, same size as input image, filled with 64, to make less saturated
S = Image.new('L', (im.width, im.height), 64)
```

[image]

Comment: I should say that these images are PNGs on a translucent background. Would that change anything? I've tried the code you provided and the image has had its colors reversed.

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to the OG transparent PNG

Comment: What's an OG background? I don't understand why your images aren't like the one you shared in your question?

Comment: The images I post initially were screen grabs of the pngs to show the gradients on a dark background. By OG I mean the "original". I realize I should have posted the original transparent PNG.

Comment: It's late here. Use `alpha = im.getchannel('A')` to grab the alpha channel from the original at the start. Then use `RGB.putchannel(alpha)` at the end to restore the original image's alpha to the result.

Comment: I am getting an error saying "AttributeError: putchannel" for some reason.

Comment: Sorry `RGB.putalpha(alpha)`

Comment: Cool - glad we got there in the end. Good luck with your project.